# Can BIRT be used as a test-bed for a logging program?

Tags: eclipse, birt

I'm trying to model an autonomic computing system. Can I use BIRT as the  test-bed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIRT is a *reporting* tool (and which, despite its name, has very little business intelligence at all - we switched from BIRT to Cognos BI for exactly that reason).

You can certainly use it to generate reports showing how your autonomic system is doing but all you would be doing is gathering the data from somewhere and presenting it.

I can't see BIRT being used in any other meaningful way for a test bed for *any* type of system.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - it cleared up alot for me.